# IE11 SVG transform: translate not working

Tags: css, animation, svg, css-animations, internet-explorer-11

I want to animate a circle

```css
@keyframes animation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate(50%, 50%);
    transform: translate(50%, 50%);
  }
}

.circle {
  animation: animation 1s ease-in;
  fill: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<svg class="parent" width="500px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <circle class="circle" r="150" cx="150" cy="150"></circle>
</svg>
```

The animation for opacity succeeded while the transform(translate) animation faild.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

IE 11 may supports the transform attribute, but it doesn't recognize the CSS style (and therefore also no CSS stylesheets or animations).

Will **not work** in IE11:

```html
<circle style="transform:translate(50%, 50%)"></circle>
```

Will **work** in IE11:

```html
<circle transform="translate(50%, 50%)"></circle>
```

I have four solutions for you:

- Go the hard way: Animate the changes with jQuery manually by using `var circles = jQuery('.circle');` to get the circles, `circles.attr('transform', 'translate('+n+'%, '+n+'%)');` to set the attribute and `jQuery.animate(...)` to get the animation steps.
- Handle the animation with `width` and `height` attributes.
- Make the animation different if IE11.
- Drop your IE11 support for that feature or your hole site.

Answer (score 0):

The IE browser does not support CSS transforms on SVG elements, more detail information, please check [this article](https://caniuse.com/#search=transform).

As a workaround, you could try to display the circle using div, instead of SVG. Code like this:

```
<head>
<style> 
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

@keyframes example {
  0%   {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;-webkit-transform: translate(0, 0); transform: translate(0, 0);opacity: 0;}

  100% {background-color:red;  -webkit-transform: translate(100%, 100%); transform: translate(100%, 100%);opacity: 1;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body> 
<div></div>

</body>
```

The output as below (use IE 11 browser):

[image]